# Experiencing issues with overwriting previous instance of ArrayList object initialization

Tags: java, arraylist, instance

EDIT: I may have fixed it by making the instance variable static? If so, why does this fix it? This was something my prof glossed over in my intro to OOP class, so I never really learned about it.

so, I'm not sure if I'm using terrible coding practice and just don't realize it, but I'm having a single crippling issue with my program, despite this one issue, everything appears to be running fine.

This program takes strings from an argument file and executes the commands based on  the instructions. However, when I issue the command "x = x + 5" I experience a crippling issue.

My class titled Work creates another instance of my other class Read. When it does this, the ArrayList that I define at the top of Read is overwritten with a new instance, and thus, deletes the whole list of variables. I'm unable to find a way to make the initialization execute only once. Where am I going wrong?

Work:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Work {

static int Precedence(char ch){
    switch (ch){
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;

        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '%':
            return 2;

        case '^':
            return 3;
    }
    return -1;
}

String infixConverter(String infix){

    Variable tvar = new Variable(); //consider removing these~
    Read reader = new Read();
    String pfix = new String("");
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

    for (int i=0; i<infix.length(); ++i) {
        char curr = infix.charAt(i);
      //  if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(curr)||curr==' ') {
        if (Character.isDigit(curr)||curr==' ') {
            pfix += curr;
        }
        else if (Character.isLetter(curr)){
          //  Read reader = new Read();
            if (reader.varExists(curr)){
              //  Variable tvar = new Variable();
               int n = reader.getIndex(curr);
               tvar = reader.vars.get(n);
               pfix += tvar.getValue();
            }
            else{
                //error
            }
            //implement this below
            //check for letter within the string, if the string is

        }

        else if (curr == '('){
            stack.push(curr);
        }
        else if (curr == ')'){
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(') {
                pfix += stack.pop();
            }

            if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(') {
                return "Invalid Expression"; // invalid expression
            }
            else {
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
        else {
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && Precedence(curr) <= 
Precedence(stack.peek())) {
                pfix += stack.pop();
            }
            stack.push(curr);
        }
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        pfix += stack.pop();
    }
    int sol = postfixEvaluation(pfix);
    pfix = Integer.toString(sol);
    return pfix;
}


Integer postfixEvaluation(String pfix){
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < pfix.length(); i++){
            char curr = pfix.charAt(i);

            if(curr == ' '){
                continue;
            }

            else if(Character.isDigit(curr)){
                int num = 0;

                while(Character.isDigit(curr)){
                    num = num*10 + (int)(curr-'0');
                        i++;
                    if (i==pfix.length()){break;}
                    curr = pfix.charAt(i);
                }
                i--;

                stack.push(num);
                //include variables and be able to insert them into here
            }

            else{
                int val1 = stack.pop();
                int val2 = stack.pop();

                switch(curr){
                    case '+':
                        stack.push(val2+val1);
                        break;

                    case '-':
                        stack.push(val2-val1);
                        break;

                    case '/':
                        stack.push(val2/val1);
                        break;

                    case '%':
                        stack.push(val2%val1);
                        break;

                    case '*':
                        stack.push(val2*val1);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return stack.pop();
    }
}
```

Read:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Read {
ArrayList<Variable> vars = new ArrayList<Variable>();//FIX THIS SHIT AHHHHHHHHH
Variable tempvar = new Variable();
Work eval = new Work();
private int lnNum = 1;
private String arg="";
public void thing() {
String thing,thing2;
if (arg.contains("print")){
    String real="";
    int i = arg.indexOf('t');
    if (i!=4){}//error
    thing = arg.substring(0,i);
    if (thing!="print"){}//error
    thing2 = arg.substring(i+2,arg.length());
    real = eval.infixConverter(thing2);
    System.out.println(real);
}
else if (arg.contains("read")){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = arg.indexOf('d');
    if (i!=3){}//error
    thing = arg.substring(0,i+1);
    if (thing!="read"){}//error
    thing2 = arg.substring(i+2,arg.length());
    char c2 = thing2.charAt(0);
        if (thing2.length()>1){}//error
    System.out.println("Enter a value for "+thing2+": ");
        String vv = in.nextLine();
        vv = eval.infixConverter(vv);
        int vvv = Integer.parseInt(vv);
        tempvar.setValue(c2, vvv);
        vars.add(tempvar);



}

else if (arg.contains("=")){
   int i = arg.indexOf('=');
   int tempval;
   thing = arg.substring(0,i-1);
   thing2 = arg.substring(i+2,arg.length());
    if(thing.length()>1){}//error
    thing2=eval.infixConverter(thing2);
    char c = thing.charAt(0);
    if (vars.contains(thing)){
        tempval = Integer.parseInt(thing2);
        tempvar.setValue(c,tempval);
        int f = vars.indexOf(thing);
    }
    else if(Character.isLetter(c)){
        tempval = Integer.parseInt(thing2);
        tempvar.setValue(c,tempval);
        vars.add(tempvar);
    }

    else{
        //error
    }
}

else{

}
}

boolean varExists(char c){
    for (int i = 0; i<vars.size(); i++){
        tempvar = vars.get(i);
        if (tempvar.getTitle()==c){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int getIndex(char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= vars.size(); i++) {
        tempvar = vars.get(i);
        if (tempvar.getTitle() == c) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int inLineNum(){
lnNum++;
return lnNum;
}

void setArg(String c){
arg=c;
}

}
```

Comment: "*ArrayList that I define at the top of Read is overwritten with a new instance*" What makes you say that? Each instance of `Read` get its own instance of `vars`.

Comment: So, then the reason Static fixes it is because it then means that there's only one instance of that variable now?

Comment: I'd say `static` **gives the illusion of** having fixed it because, yes, all instances of `Read` now share a single `vars` variable.  The real issue is that the design of the `Read` class is such that it just won't work well if you create and use more than one instance of it.

Comment: How should I have designed it?